# Telegram set Not Found for InlineQueryResults

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

In Telegram `InlineQueryResults` when we have items to show for requested , we can show our items. **But** when we have no items for showing, How to show `Not Found` item with `No Message Creation` after select that?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible for now, you can only try to send simple text with error description.

Comment: Are you sure? is not any way?

Comment: I am not sure, but I use bot for almost a year